# Using Handlebars.js precompiled templates with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, handlebars.js, knockout-2.0

## Steps

1. Added the runtime handlebars `handlebars.runtime.js`
2. Html reference: `<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'HtmlTemplates/Passos/rowPassos.html', foreach: Passos }"></tbody>`
3. Console Error *Uncaught Error: Cannot find template with ID HtmlTemplates/Passos/rowPassos.html*

[image: Knockoutjs with handlebars.js]

The error occurs because the Knockoutjs not work with Handlebars natively.
The question is, how to use precompiled templates ( handlebars.js) with knockoutjs?

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to use Handlebars since Knockout itself can do many of the tempting-like things which Handlebars does.

Comment: Knockoutjs has precompiled templates?
I need performance, so I chose handlebars and compile the templates.
Another detail is that these templates are used elsewhere in the application.

Comment: No, Knockout doesn't have pre-compiled templates, so if you're after performance then Handlebars.js is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

*A little late, but better late than never I guess.*

Knockout works with template ID's. (`<script id=".."></script>`) Not with HTML files. I personally have no experience with handlebars, so I can't comment on that.

However, you seem to be using precompiling, so I guess these HTML files live on a server, and not inline.

Therefore, you should use [external templates](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine). I'm using it as well and it works awesome.

In your case, instead of giving it `HtmlTemplates/Passos/rowPassos.html` you should give KnockOut `HtmlTemplates/Passos/rowPassos` (so without the .html) and external templates should fetch it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have precompiled your handlebars template, then you can go ahead and use the `html` data-bind in `ko`.

Something like this:

```
var myTemplate = Handlebars.compile('<span class="strong {{#is option optimalValue}}ok{{else}}bad{{/is}}">SOMEVALUE</span>');
<span data-bind="html: myTemplate({option:5, optimalValue:4})"></span>
```